# persist and flush objects from a session

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, flush

I have two controllers, one that record the modified entities and put them in a session:

```
public function update_accountAction(Request $request)
{   
    Try
    {
        $code = $request->request->get('code'); 
        $name = $request->request->get('name'); 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle:Accounttree');

        $to_change = new Accounttree();
        $to_change = $repo->findOneByCode($code);

        $to_change->setName($name);
        $to_change->setCode($code);

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $entity_to_update = $session->get('entity_to_update');

        $counter = $session->get('number_of_changes');

        $entity_to_update[] = $to_change;  

        $counter = $counter +1;

        $session->set('number_of_changes',$counter);
        $session->set('entity_to_update',serialize($entity_to_update));


        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, "modified" => $entity_to_update);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    Catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => false, "error" => $e);
        return new Response($response);
    }

}
```

And another one that loop on the results, and if it's actually one of the desired object persist it. Finally I flush.

```
public function save_changesAction()
 {
     Try
     {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

         $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

         $entity_to_update = unserialize($session->get('entity_to_update'));


         foreach($entity_to_update as $account)
         {
             if($account->getId())
             {                     
                $em->persist($account); 
                echo $account->getId();
             }
             else
             {
                   echo "error";
             }
         }

         $em->flush();
         $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, "modified" => $account->getId());
         return new Response(json_encode($response));
     }
     Catch(Exception $e)
     {
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => false, "error" => $e);
        return new Response($response);
     }

}
```

So the result of this is:
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: 000000007a60b041000000007ae6afd8 in /home/eagle1/www/Symfony24/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2852

I don't understand why, because it seems that I get back a fully functional object (I can execute its functions, access its property and it seems also that the persist is working...

Somebody knows the answer ?

Comment: What is in line 2852?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not just saving the id of the entity along with the two strings (name and code) in the session ... instead you try to store the complete entity (with all the doctrine proxy stuff) ? you could easily just fetch the entities from the repository in your save-action.

Comment: you are right for this case I could do as you say. However when I'll want to change the parent I'm gonna have to have the entity. Unless I can set the parent myself (not using the method addchild advised in the doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull object from session, it is not managed by doctrine. You have to merge it back to notify entity manager about it.

```
if($account->getId())
{                     
    $account = $em->merge($account);
    $em->persist($account); 
    echo $account->getId();
 }
```

Doctrine has manual section for [Entities in the Session](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html)

Comment: Doctrine manual page has moved: [Entities in the Session](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html)